# JS ajax event to by input change

Tags: javascript

I would like to have this code so I because if I go into the other input field, the other is updated

Or secound better input change

```js
// on click search results...
$(document).on("touchend", "#ean", function() {
  var value = $("#ean").val();
  if (value.length != 0) {
    //alert(99933);
    searchData(value);
  } else {
    $('#search-result-container').hide();
  }
});

// This function helps to send the request to retrieve data from mysql database...
function searchData(val) {
  $('#search-result-container').show();
  $('#search-result-container').html('<div><img src="app/ajax-artstk/preloader.gif" width="50px;" height="50px"> <span style="font-size: 20px;">Please Wait...</span></div>');
  $.post('app/ajax-artstk/controller.php', {
    'ean': val
  }, function(data) {

    if (data != "")
      $('#search-result-container').html(data);
    else
      $('#search-result-container').html("<div class='search-result'><div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">No Result Found...</div></div>");
  }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?

    alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error

  });
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="ausgang">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="control-label"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="ean" class="control-label">EAN</label>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="ean" class="form-control" id="ean" value="" maxLength="100" autofocus>
        <div id="search-result-container" style="border:solid 0px #BDC7D8;display:none; "></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="stueck" class="control-label">- Stück</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="stk" class="form-control" id="stk" value="" maxLength="3">
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Entnehmen</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">S</button>
        <!-- PRINTBUTTON -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END form-group -->
</form>
```

who can help me please who the very nice of you have already tried everything so far

I want to use that via Android and Windows 7 Firefox browser.

I thank you very much for the help that I get I would like to ask to send any links where it is poorly explained

Comment: What do you mean by "the other is updated"? The other what?

Comment: Your English is very poor, maybe you can have a friend help translate for you.

Comment: google sry for my English

Comment: i have my problem solved...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
// on click search results...
$('body').on('change', '#ean', function() { 
     var value = $("#ean").val(); 
     if (value.length != 0) {
        //alert(99933);
        searchData(value);
    } else {     
         $('#search-result-container').hide();
    }    
});

// This function helps to send the request to retrieve data from mysql database...
function searchData(val){
    $('#search-result-container').show();
    $('#search-result-container').html('<div><img src="app/ajax-artstk/preloader.gif" width="50px;" height="50px"> <span style="font-size: 20px;">Please Wait...</span></div>');
    $.post('app/ajax-artstk/controller.php',{'ean': val}, function(data){

        if(data != "")
            $('#search-result-container').html(data);
        else                
        $('#search-result-container').html("<div class='search-result'><div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">No Result Found...</div></div>");
    }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?

    alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error

    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: A good answer should contain an explanation of the problem in the original code and how the answer fixes it, not just show new code. It's hard to tell what you changed this way.

Comment: The only change you made was to change `$('body')` to `$(document)`. If you put your code inside `$(document).ready()` I don't think that should be necessary. It's also not clear why you're using delegation in the first place, why not just `$('#ean').on('change')`. Is the input added dynamically?